# Selenium Robot Framework - Get Table Cell

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm wondering is it possible to `click` span element, which is located in `div` element and this `div` element is situated inside the `table cell`?

So in the end table looks like this:

```
<table id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tr1">
      <td id="td11">
        <div id="div1">
          <span id="span1">TEXT</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td id="td12">
      </td>
    <tr>
    <tr id="tr2">
      <td id="tr21"></td>
      <td id="tr22"></td>
    <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And I'm trying to click `span` element like this:

```
${table_cell} =   Get Table Cell   xpath=//table[contains(@id,'table1')]/tbody   1   1
Click Element    ${table_cell}
```

But I'm getting error:

> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

So first I added control, if there is this `table` element and it tells me **TRUE** every time:

```
${present} =    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    xpath=//table[contains(@id,'table1')]/tbody
Run Keyword If    ${present}    log to console    \nTABLE CELL ELEMENT EXISTS - ${present}
```

Can you give a advice what am I doing wrong?
Is there any different behavior if this table is in `iframe`?

Comment: Yes there is. If the table is in an `iframe` you need to select the iframe itself first by using the keyword `Select Frame  <selector>`

Comment: and do I have to save the value or result of "Select Frame <selector>" into some variable to use it later?

Comment: no, as it not returns any value by default. See the corresponding documentation: 

http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20Frame